# Similar claim to: If $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$, then $f \circ g$ is continuous at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I came up with the following claim and **wanted to check with you all if it was correct or not**:

If $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = a,$ and $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(a).$

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta,$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon.$ Now, let $\delta' > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta'$, then $|g(x) - a| < \delta.$ Then it follows that $|f(g(x)) - f(a)| < \epsilon.$

Thank you!

Comment: Good news: it's right. Bad news: It's a completely standard result.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's actually false. Suppose $f(0)=1, f=0$ elsewhere. Then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0.$  Let $g(x) = x\sin(1/x), x\ne 0.$ Then $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0.$ Does $\lim_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) =0.$ No, in fact the limit doesn't exist. To see this, let $A=\{1/(n\pi): n\in \mathbb Z\}.$ For $x\in A,$ $f(g(x))=1,$ while at all other $x\ne 0,$ $f(g(x))=0.$

Comment: @zhw: Right, needs some qualifications.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You’re right; posted too quickly. I’ve removed the comment, in case you want to delete yours as well.